# Помогите составить регулярное выражение на языке php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
$str = '[68551198 68554976], [68551198 68554976 68555019 68555024 68555030]';
```

Помогите мне написать регулярное выражение, которое возвращало бы первое вхождение между двумя символами, я хотел бы получить следующий результат

```
$output = '68551198 68554976';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только для первого вхождения:

```php
$re = '/(?<=\[)\d+ \d+/';
$str = '[68551198 68554976], [68551198 68554976 68555019 68555024 68555030]';

preg_match($re, $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 0);
```

Для всех первых вхождений:

```php
$re = '/(?<=\[)\d+ \d+/';
$str = '[68551198 68554976], [68551198 68554976 68555019 68555024 68555030]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```

Comment: Подскажите еще пожалуйста, у меня строка с символами которые нужно перед этим удалить $str = 'данных номенклатур не было [68551198 68554976], данных номенклатур не было [68551198 68554976 68555019 68555024 68555030]'; Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: @ВладленАлексей: выражение и так должно извлекать только необходимые числа, игнорируя другие последовательности.

Comment: Я понял, только изначально не известно сколько данных в первом значении, может быть и 5 шт к примеру $str = '[68551198 68554976], [68551198 68554976 68555019 68555024 68555030], [68555024 68555030]';

Comment: @ВладленАлексей: исходя из предоставленных входных данных и результата, выражение должно работать. Если работает не так, как нужно, то дополните вопрос примерами.